# Cardano Node 1.35.4 problems

Tags: cardano-node

I am running cardano node 1.35.4 on Windows 10 it syncs to 100% then gives me the following screen
[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you are asking about `Unsupported remote target address ...` errors (ipv6), then I suspect that you start the node only specifying `IPv4` address.  To get `IPv6` address either:

- do not specify ip addresses at all (then the node should discover which addresses the host machine supports); or
- specify both `IPv4` and `IPv6`

If you just specify one of them, the node will only bind to that address, and be able to use outbound connections using that IP version.  This allows us to support environments where `IPv4` or `IPv6` is not available.

Comment: Thanks for your help , I am currently not specifying any IP address 
cardano-node run --topology "configuration\cardano\testnet-topology.json" --database-path "db" --socket-path "\\.\pipe\cardano-node-testnet" --port 3001 --config "configuration\cardano\testnet-config.json"